# UIWebView Delegate Methods not Working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

**When I Use `self.myWeview.delegate = self` ,
`UIWebView` can not load `URL` in `UIWebView`...
But If I set it to `self.myWeview.delegate = nil`,
then methods(delegate) can't load but `URL` is load 
this is the code:---

```
{
   self.myWeview.delegate = nil;
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [myWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

This is working fine but couldn't called delegate methods.

On the other hand

```
{
   self.myWeview.delegate = self;
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:http://www.google.com"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [myWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

It Couldn't load `URL` but calls the delegate methods

Comment: Error : [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; check it on second code

Comment: remove extra http: from url.

Comment: what you are processing in delegate method?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a mistake in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I got my answer by lot of experiment,if we not using this method

```
    -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

except that all methods are working fine in UIwebViewDelegate

```
1. -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
2. -(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
3. -(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Answer (score 1):

remove that extra `http`

```
    {
       self.myWeview.delegate = self;
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
       NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       [myWebView loadRequest:request];
    }
```

Comment: actually ,its by mistake put extra http
but i am not using extra http,
but it also gives same result,
my delegate methoda not working

Answer (score 1):

You have made the mistake in calling the URL ...

Try this  :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your viewcontroller.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

set delegate to self then you need to implement the delegate

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
   return YES;
}
```

and also don't forget to confirm the protocol in .h file like this

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```