# UIwebView Delegate methods not working why?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

When I use `self.myWeview.delegate = self`, my `UIwebView` instance cannot load a URL. If I set it  to `nil` then the delegate methods don't fire, but but the URL is loaded.

Here's my code:

```
      self.myWeview.delegate = nil;
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
      NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      [myWebView loadRequest:request];
```

It works fine but doesn't call delegate methods. Here's an example where I assign the delegate methods:

```
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; 
     NSURLRequest request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [myWebView loadRequest:request];
```

What's wrong?

Comment: what have u returned from this delegate method `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

Comment: You asked the ***exact same question*** some 20 minutes ago... ***DON'T!***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289990/uiwebview-delegate-methods-not-working by same user @chandanwtb duplicate question is not allowed in SO

Comment: beacause of this: `self.myWeview.delegate = nil;`

Comment: You have already got the answers for this issue in your previous duplicate question of the same problem. First try those solutions. Don't ask same problem's, same question again.

Comment: try another rather than www.google.com
like www.yahoo.com

Answer (score 5):

You need to set:

```
self.myWeview.delegate = self;
```

And in .h file:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Unless you don't set delegate to `self` delegate method will not get called.

Comment: # I do it in my .h file but wont't work #

Comment: # I do it in my .h file but wont't work after setting it my URL is not loaded,but methods are called #

Comment: URL not loading have nothing to do with setting delegate to self. Download this test project https://github.com/rptwsthi/TrickTest in which i have checked for the condition and look for `FLViewController` then find the code code for `webView` at bottom most method name id `loadUrlOnWebView`. you can run this project to see that url is loading.

Answer (score 2):

One thing is important that where ever you use uiwebview set it's properties 'strong' and 'nonatomic' instead of 'retain'.

Generally we use 'strong' property in only appdelegate class and retain in other viewcontroller classes.

But for uiwebview in viewcontroller class also you have to set property 'strong'.

Comment: I did that,but still it not working

Comment: strong is about arc..

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `protocol` `UIWebViewDelegate` in .h file
Like : `@interface yourClass:inheritedClass<UIWebViewDelegate>` and set the delegate   `self.myWeview.delegate = self
;`

Comment: I do it in my .h file but wont't work